# What is the different between --max-items and limits in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using `aws sdk` in `nodejs` for querying dynamodb. There is a limit parameter which to tell the query the max items in the response. The problem on using `limit` is that the query filter applies after limit which means it returns less than the limit. I am looking for a way to put `limit` after `filter` but it seems there is no such good solution. I will have to run more queries until I get the expected limits.

When I search dyanmodb doc I found that there is a `--max-items` in the aws cli. I wonder does the `--max-items` work the same way as the `limit` in the sdk? I see someone mention that this parameter works after filter. If it is true, can I use something in the node sdk to achieve the same goal?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how `max-items` in the CLI works. However as far as the JS library is concerned, `limit` is your only built in option. This question however makes me wonder what your use case is and if you are using DynamoDB in an efficient manner. Your only real option here is to make multiple requests to DynamoDB if the items aren't retrieved. However, that will eat up a bunch of latency and back and forth requests, and isn't very efficient or scalable at all.

Comment: Do you mean using limit and filter is not an efficient manner? i am saving order transaction data in dynamodb and support users query their order by a few attributes such as `price`, `status`, `category` etc.